# Query Failed Error: UError: Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing. bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to update existing BigQUery table with data from second existing BigQUery table and running into problems. Rusty on SQL and new to BigQuery.

> "Query Failed Error: Table name "IFSalesTable" cannot be resolved:
>   dataset name is missing."

```
INSERT INTO IFSalesTable ( DEPCityPower_Distance, DEPCityIndividualismVSCollectivism, DEPCityMasculinityVSFemininity, DEPCityUncertainty_Avoidance, DEPCityLong_Short_term_Orientation, DEPCityIndulgence, DEPCityEstVal, DEPCityEstCtnry )
SELECT Power_Distance, IndividualismVSCollectivism, MasculinityVSFemininity, Uncertainty_Avoidance, Long_Short_term_Orientation, Indulgence, EstVal, EstCtnry
FROM IFSalesDataSet.CulturalValues
WHERE CulturalValues.Code = IFSalesTable.DEP_AP
```

[image: image1 screen shot showing CulturalValues source table]

[image: image2 screen shot showing start of IFSalesTable target table (i.e. lookup variable DEP_AP)]

[image: image3 screen shot showing end of IFSalesTable target table (i.e. target vars for insert)]

Thanks in advance for clear newbie level guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just simply add dataset name into `INSERT INTO IFSalesTable` so it will be `INSERT INTO IFSalesDataSet.IFSalesTable`

Comment: Thanks for the thought Mikhail, I tried the following with the same result :( Any other thoughts?
INSERT INTO IFSalesDataSet.IFSalesTable ( DEPCityPower_Distance, DEPCityIndividualismVSCollectivism, EstCtnry
FROM IFSalesDataSet.CulturalValues
WHERE IFSalesDataSet.CulturalValues.Code = IFSalesDataSet.IFSalesTable.DEP_AP

Comment: is it exactly same error as before? that would be strange